# Using join feature on ArcGIS Online to create a hosted feature layer view to append most recent record from related table to location

Tags: arcgis-online, hosted-feature-layer

I currently use Field Maps for ArcGIS to carry out tree inspections. The design consists of two part - a feature class layer which contains a polygon for each inspection zone including data such as its name and ranking; and a related table which contains inspection information such as date of inspection and next inspection date. The two are related using a 1:many relationship class based on a shared GlobalID field (based on https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/field-mobility/field-mobility/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/).

I am trying to use the Join Features tool on Map Viewer Classic to create a hosted feature layer view of the inspections zones so that they can be symbolised based on their most recent inspection data. On the Join Features tool I am selecting the option to 'define which record is kept' ordered by the newest inspection date.

The resulting hosted feature layer view is not showing the most recent inspection and it just showing the first related record for each area - I am not sure why this is happening/if there is another method which can achieve the same results.